# Redirect 2 commands to a file on the same line script

Tags: bash, scripts

I need to make a script that returns 2 commands to a file.

But i would like them to be on the same line in the file.

The first command i want to use is `speedtest-cli --csv` and the second command is `date '+%H:%M'`

I searched on the internet and i found this:

> { date '+%H:%M' ; speedtest-cli --csv;} >> output.csv;

But when i use this the output file contains this:

```
21:18
11458,MyTheValentinus,Roubaix,2017-12-15T20:18:43.049067Z,34.53116198582131,32.416,20496907.000490207,3872939.885024341
```

while it needs to be on the same line.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to produce a valid `.csv` with **c**omma **s**eparated **v**alues instead of having the time along with the first cell value of `speedtest-cli --csv` together in the first cell, then these commands should help (both doing the same thing):

```bsh
printf "%s,%s" $(date +%R) "$(speedtest-cli --csv)" >>output.csv
echo $(date +%R),"$(speedtest-cli --csv)" >>output.csv
```

`date +%R` by the way is the same as `date +%H:%M`, whose format specifier doesn't need to be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Write like this:

```
{ printf "$(date '+%H:%M') "; speedtest-cli --csv; } >> output.csv
```

Or like this:

```
echo "$(date '+%H:%M') $(speedtest-cli --csv)" >> output.csv
```

Your approach didn't work because the `date` command produces output with a newline automatically appended.

When wrapped in a `$(...)`, the last newline is not printed.